# How to interact between html5/js code and Windows Phone 8 native code?

Tags: javascript, html, authentication, windows-phone-8, hybrid-mobile-app

so I already have a web mobile version of an app and I want to make it into an actual windows phone 8 app using the webbrowser view. I have a login form in my "index.html" and I want to save the username and password to the device, so the user will be automatically logged in the next time the app is opened. Is it possible to do this? If so, how exactly do I accomplish this?

For example, if I have a function in my MainPage.xaml.cs, can I somehow call that function using javascript?

Also, I'm not sure if I need to use PhoneGap. I'm not using/accessing any native features like camera or contacts supported by PhoneGap in my app, so I just used the html5 template for windows phone 8. I've look at sample projects, but I could only find html5 games.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use PhoneGap. The default HTML5 template should be sufficient for your described needs.

You can call from C# to JS using the `InvokeScript` method.

You can call from JS to C# using `window.external.Notify();`.

Storing passwords is normally a bad idea due to the security implications. If you must do this be sure to [encrypt the data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh487164%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) when stored.

Comment: Thanks for clearing up my questions about PhoneGap and the link for encrypting password is helpful as well. I'll look more into those two functions. Thanks!